# Power bi desktop mobile view background problem

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am trying to apply the background for the mobile view I have used the background image for the desktop view but Im not able to apply it in mobile view why I am facing this issue in the visulization pan I am not able to see any canvas setting to format  [Check this image=>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e97I5.png)

So I am expecting that help me to fix this issue and tell me how can I apply background image for the mobile view